# How to make one part function from this function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, special-functions, absolute-value

I want to turn below function from multipart function to a one part function ,like example:
example $$f(x)=\begin{cases}3x+1 & x\geq0\\x+1 & x < 0\end{cases} \\\to f(x)=2x+|x|+1$$
now my goal is to turn $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2+x-2& x\leq -3\\4-3x-x^2& -3< x <1\\x^2+3x-4 & x\geq 1\end{cases}$$
I get stuck on this problem . can anybody help me ?

Comment: Can you guess what abs function does it have  ?

Comment: I will point out that for real numbers $|x|=\begin{cases}x&\text{if}~x\geq 0\\ -x&\text{if}~x<0\end{cases}$.  I am curious then why you would consider $f(x)=|x|$ to be a "one part function" as opposed to a "multipart function."  What makes it any more or less one-part or multipart to you?  How do you define a "one part function" and how do you define a "multipart function" in the first place?

Comment: @JMoravitz The question is clear I believe. Why are you making things so difficult? Multipart function = piecewice function, so it is a well-defined mathematical concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise

Answer (score 1):

As you function brrak at $x=-3,+1 $  so must have $|(x-1)(x+3)|$ in it .
so ,we can assume that $$f(x)=|(x-1)(x+3)|+g(x)$$ now look for break points
$$x\geq 1 \to f(x)=x^2+2x-3+g(x)\\-3\leq x\leq 1 \to f(x)=-x^2-2x+3+g(x)$$ now compare with the original function

$$x\geq 1 \to f(x)=x^2+2x-3+g(x)=x^2+x-2 \implies g(x)=x-1\\-3\leq x\leq 1 \to f(x)=-x^2-2x+3+g(x)=-x^2-3x+4 \implies g(x)=-x+1$$ those implies $$g(x)=|x-1|$$ so merge three part of function in one part as below:$$f(x)=f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2+x-2& x\leq -3\\4-3x-x^2& -3< x <1\\x^2+3x-4 & x\geq 1\end{cases}\\=|(x-1)(x+3)|+|x-1|$$